# Forward TCP requests from host to container on specific port

Tags: docker, docker-network

I am running the container and mapping the port like so:

```
docker run -d --expose 4242 -p 4242:4242 42wim/matterbridge:stable --debug
```

I've created a firewall rule to allows TCP connections over port `4242` to my VM. When I send an http request to the public IP of my VM the connection is refused:

```
http://{public-ip}:4242/api/messages
```

Howevever if I open a shell into the container and do a curl to the path I get the expected response `curl localhost:4242/api/messages`

What is the correct way to map TCP requests on port 4242 from my Host to my Container? I'm running a Ubuntu VM on GCP that hosts my docker container

**Update**, if use `docker run --network="host"` I can curl from the host to the docker container with `curl localhost:4242/api/messages` with the expected response. Yet when I do the same curl request with the public IP the connection is still refused.

if I `ss -na | grep :4242`

`tcp LISTEN 0 4096 127.0.0.1:4242 0.0.0.0:*`

it shows it's listening. Is there additional mapping I need to do? I have validated from google firewall logs that it is allowing and forwarding TCP connections from port 4242 to the VM

Comment: That `docker run -p` option should do it; you may need to check that the process inside the container is listening on the special 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address, if it listens on 127.0.0.1 it won't be reachable from outside its container (or from off-host if you disable Docker networking with `--net host`).  But otherwise, this seems like a firewall-configuration problem and not a programming issue.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have validated that it's letting connections through to the VM on 4242, but they are not reaching my container. If I pass the `--network="host"` flag I can `curl ...` from the host VM but it is still not reachable externally